# detecting computers with same MAC address and same IP address as well

Tags: duplicates, arp, cloning, scapy

On a LAN how do I detect computers which have same MAC address and same IP address (given by DHCP) as well?

In my LAN, this is a common problem because of VM cloning going on all the time.

So far what I have tried:

```
 1) arping -c 10 -b -D -I eth2 172.20.10.108
    ARPING 172.20.10.108 from 0.0.0.0 eth2
    Unicast reply from 172.20.10.108 [00:50:56:82:00:00]  0.783ms
    Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
    Received 1 response(s)  ==> I was expecting this to be 3, since I have 3 computers with same MAC and same IP as well.
```

I already have a working script using scapy to detect computers with same MAC but different IP address.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Scapy. I have created a ticket at http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/ticket/769

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using PacketFu (Ruby library). I can now detect computers with same (or different) MAC address and same IP addres.